# Android:Name Attribute in Manifest Causing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-manifest

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.2.2 and migrated to the new Firebase SDK. With this migration, I had to add google-services.json file to my app to support some of the new Firebase features.

Previously (before upgrading to 2.2.2 and migrating to the new Firebase), I was able to run my app with no issues. However, I am now receiving the following error immediately when trying to run the application:

```
  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.troychuinard.fanpolls, PID: 12116
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 12 more
               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I am able to "fix" this issue by removing the `android:name` attribute from my manifest:

Previous:

[image]

New: (this method works):

[image]

I am not sure if this is the correct fix, as I was previously able to use the `android:name` attribute in my manifest with no issues. I am trying to figure out what is causing this error and how I can resolve correctly.

Comment: do you have a class that extends Application class?

Comment: No, my activities all extend AppCompatActivity, my fragments all extend a version of fragment, and my model classes extend nothing. When would I extend application? I have never really heard of doing that..

Comment: What do you mean in "ss." I am simply confused as to why it previously worked and now it does not...

Comment: you should name attribute if you have a class that extends Application class. it is also referred as SingleTon class